# Seg fault while implementing malloc, realloc, free in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free, realloc

I am implementing a simple version of malloc, realloc, and free for an assignment and having trouble debugging. My code seems to be working for malloc, but the realloc tests are resulting in a seg fault. Specifically, the pointer passed to free() seems to be the problem.

There is a "free list" to manage the list of previously allocated blocks of memory. Each node in this list maintains the next and previous blocks, and an int free which is set to 1 when the memory is available, 0 otherwise.

```
void *mm_malloc(size_t size) {
    if (size <= 0) return NULL;

    struct list_node *node;
    if (!list_head) {
        node = request_block(size);
        list_head = node;
        list_tail = node;
    } else {
        node = get_free_block(size);
        if (!node) { //no available existing block
            node = request_block(size);
            if (!node) { //request failed
                return NULL;
            }
        } else { //available existing block
            //TODO: split block
            node->free = 0;
        }
    }
    return memset(node+1, 0, node->size);
}

void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    if (size <= 0) return NULL;
    if (!ptr) return mm_malloc(size);

    struct list_node *node = (struct list_node*)ptr - 1;
    if (node->size >= size) {
        // TODO: free extra space
        return ptr;
    }
    void *new_block = mm_malloc(size);
    if (!new_block) return NULL;
    memcpy(new_block, ptr, node->size);
    free(ptr); //Error happens with this call.
    return new_block;
}

void mm_free(void *ptr) {
    if (!ptr) return;
    struct list_node *node = (struct list_node*)ptr - 1;
    node->free = 1;
}
```

EDIT: left out some important helper functions

```
struct list_node *get_free_block(size_t size) {
    struct list_node *curr = list_head;
    while (curr && !(curr->free && curr->size >= size)) {
        curr = curr->next;
    } return curr;
}

struct list_node *request_block(size_t size) {
    struct list_node *node = sbrk(0);
    void *request = sbrk(size + NODE_SIZE);
    if (request == (void*) -1) { // attempted sbrk failed
        return NULL;
    }
    if (list_tail) {
        node->prev = list_tail;
        list_tail->next = node;
        list_tail = node;
    }
    node->next = NULL;
    node->free = 0;
    node->size = size;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see for sure because you have not provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, where is `request_block`? But it does look like the classic mistake of allocating a block and then returning a data pointer (that is `node+1`) but then freeing the data pointer rather than the original memory block.

Comment: Oh, you are calling `sbrk` not `malloc`. Then you shouldn't be calling `free`. Did you mean to call `mm_free` instead of `free` in `mm_realloc`?

Comment: Thanks @kaylum that was exactly my problem! Silly mistake - just used to free I suppose.

Comment: I guess that's just for learning/training but mentioning it anyways: requesting *large* chunks through `sbrk()` isn't exactly efficient -- real-world implementations use `mmap()` for chunks bigger than some threshold. Also you should join adjacent free regions requested through `sbrk()`.